# i18n friendly way of stripping non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: c++, internationalization

I want to strip any non-alphanumeric characters in a string. I'm using the following function for now, but it certainly wouldn't work for many languages. Is there an i18n-friendly way of doing it?

```
static string StripNonAlphaNum(const string& token) {
    string s = token;
     // strip away non-alphanumeric parts using a RE expression
    RE2::GlobalReplace(&s, "[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the erase-remove idiom with a `std::isalnum` predicate like below:

```
std::string StripNonAlphaNum(std::string token) {
  token.erase(std::remove_if(token.begin(), token.end(), 
              [](char const &c){ return !std::isalnum(c); }), token.end());
  return token;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6889182a2c1b5e71)

The same can be implemented for `std::wstring` as well:

```
std::wstring StripNonAlphaNum(std::wstring token) {
  token.erase(std::remove_if(token.begin(), token.end(),
              [](char const &c){ return !std::iswalnum(c); }), token.end());
  return token;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0152e105d8754243)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried Korean - std::wstring token= L"1k2..dkfjls한ie=글=_=ki38.;;12_93" - and am not sure if it works. It spits out "1k2dkfjlsieki381293"

Comment: @zoolook which locale is this? Mind that you can use [`std::isalnum(std::locale)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isalnum) where you're allowed to set the locale.